# Get position of dynamic Image View

Tags: android, imageview

**Outline**

My application has a main Image View and below main view, it has dynamic horizontal imageview .

**Code for dynamic image view**

```
ImageView imageall = new ImageView(FullImage.this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(175, 175);
params.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
imageall.setLayoutParams(params);
imageall.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imageview_border);
Picasso.with(context_tab1).load("http://example.com//upload/image/" + stringList.get(in)).into(imageall);
// Adds the view to the layout
layout.addView(imageall);
imageall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            int position  = (Integer) v.getTag();
                            image = "http://example.com/x/upload/image/" + stringList.get(position);
                            Picasso.with(context_tab1).load(image).into(fullimage);

                        }
                    });
                }
```

I populate the dynamic imageview from array list. Everything works fine till this part.

**Problem**

Now, On Click of the dynmic imageview must get that image view position and change as the main imageview .

This is not working for me.

For better understanding please find the image attached.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You can get position from your arraylist or you can set tag for imageview.

Comment: @piyush gupta Can you provide few more details.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of getting position of dynamic `ImageView`..

While creating the dynamic `ImageView` you can set Ids to them and also set the `onClickListener` on them. Override the `Onclick` method, check the Id with your Ids you gave to dynamic `ImageView` and replace the Main view's as per the `ImageView` clicked..

Happy coding.. :)

Comment: Thanks. Can please tell me how to get the current image view's id??